# C# EF code-first create SQL view query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, view, ef-code-first

I was trying to create a view from EF code-first. Unfortunately after my research, I couldn't find any topics about it.

I can get my SQL view queries using EF database-first, but can't get it from code-first.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZPsV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create views inside a Migration using the Sql method:

```
public partial class Migration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.Sql("CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS (etc)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        this.Sql("DROP VIEW dbo.MyView");
    }
}
```

There's not any problem to map an entity to a view, in your dbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbQuery<MyModelView> MyView
    {
        get
        {
            // Don't track changes to query results
            return Set<MyModelView>().AsNoTracking();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF says: The entity type is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: @hakan maybe you are trying to modify the state of the entity and you can not do that..